# xfce4-terminal "Open Link" feature stopped working on XUbuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, xfce4-terminal

Recently, after a software upgrade, the "Open Link" item in my xfce4-terminal right click menu stopped working: instead of opening the clicked URL in a new Firefox tab, it now opens a whole new Firefox window showing just the Firefox starting page.

How can I fix this so that I can open links from the terminal again?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the removal of the `-remote` command-line switch in Firefox 36.  If you have Mozilla Firefox selected as your preferred browser in the Preferred Applications settings, the terminal (or, rather, `exo-open`) is still trying to use that obsolete switch, which confuses Firefox.

See [this bug report (bug #1429284)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-terminal/+bug/1429284) for more details.

In any case, there's a very simple work-around:

1. Open the Preferred Applications setting (found under Settings in the Xfce menu, or by running `exo-preferred-applications` from the command line).
2. Click the Web Browser selection menu, and select "Other..."
3. Simply type `firefox` (or, equivalently, `firefox "%s"`), in all lower case, into the dialog that opens:

   [image: Screenshot]
4. You should now have "firefox" (as opposed to "Mozilla Firefox") selected as your preferred browser.  Now just close the Preferred Applications settings, and try opening a link from your terminal — it should work normally again.